# What is the effective time interval limit for recovery right after the exercise

Tags: recovery

In the literature there are some contradictory findings about the food intake after exercise. What is the effective time to start eating after exercise and how many hours later the effectiveness decrease for recovery?

Comment: Unless you're at an advanced stage in your training, competing in long endurance events (or training like that), or training multiple times per day, then whatever is most convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my thinking and beliefs on the subject:

1) One of the most important things for muscle recovery is replenishing muscle glycogen.  Consuming carbohydrates within the first hour or two after exercise has been shown to expedite this process.

2) Since high glycemic carbs digest rapidly they work the best.

3) Since your body will respond with insulin when you consume these carbs it seems beneficial to pair it with a moderate amount of protein and amino acids ( they get shuttled into muscle tissue because of the insulin ).

Chocolate milk works great.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any value abotu as the time passes and recovery percentages?

Comment: It's kind of a long term process and it depends a lot on the individual and his or her level of fitness.  I don't think it's really a make or break kind of thing unless you are a very advanced athlete trying to outperform others.